# Android and PHP - multiple values for each row of the array

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

I want to create an array which contains multiple values(ex. Latitude,Longitude) for each row.

I've tried this in my PHP code:

```
<?php
       $latitudeFrom =$_POST['latitudeFrom'];
       $longitudeFrom =$_POST['longitudeFrom'];
       $radius=$_POST['radius'];

       $conn=mysql_connect($hostname,$user,$pass);

       $db=mysql_select_db('my_finditdatabase');

//$latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, 
       $earthRadius = 6371000;

       $ris=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Parcheggio;")or die('died');
       $riga=mysql_fetch_array($ris);
       $i=0;
       while($riga)
       {
             $latitudeTo=$riga['Latitudine'];
             $longitudeTo=$riga['Longitudine'];

             //print "lat:{$latitudeTo}   lon:{$longitudeTo}  ";
             // convert from degrees to radians
             $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
             $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
             $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
             $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);
             //print "___lat:{$latTo}___lon:{$lonTo}  ";
             $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
             $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

             $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
             cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
             $dist= $angle * $earthRadius;
             //print "====dist:{$dist}  <br>  ";
             if($dist<=$radius){
                  //print "<br><br> Ci sono  ";
                  $Citta=$riga['Citta'];
                  $Via=$riga['Via'];
                  $Provincia=$riga['Provincia'];
                  $NumCivico=$riga['NumCivico'];
                  //print "<br><br> Citta:{$Citta}--Via: {$Via}--Provincia:{$Provincia}---NumCivico:{$NumCivico}  <br>";

                  $newdata=array("Citta" => $Citta, "Provincia" => $Provincia , "Via" => $Via , "NumCivico" => $NumCivico ,"Latitude" => $latitudeTo , "Longitude" => $longitudeTo);
                  array_push($md_array[$i],$newdata);
                  $i++;
            }
            $riga=mysql_fetch_array($ris);
       }
       print(json_encode($arr));

       mysql_close();
?>
```

If it enter in the IF BLOCK it should add a row to te array with theese values:

```
 $newdata=array("Citta" => $Citta, "Provincia" => $Provincia , "Via" => $Via , "NumCivico" => $NumCivico ,"Latitude" => $latitudeTo , "Longitude" => $longitudeTo);
 array_push($md_array[$i],$newdata);
```

**I would say if this method functions and how I could print the array and read it from my Java class that makes the http request.**

Comment: so after all that, you're basically just asking how to parse/read json in a java app?

Comment: yes, but also if the array is done correctly ...

Comment: Best way would be to execute this code. Also please print what's in $riga? I suspect this code may fail as I don't see initialisation of $md_array anywhere.